# WordPress Categories vs URL Structure

Tags: wordpress

I just launched my first WordPress site, and I'm confused by WordPress' Categories feature. I would like to set it up so that I have three URL structures:

1. Regular posts display @ mysite.com/post-title
2. Posts in the category "World" display at mysite.com/world/post-title
3. Posts in the category "Issues" display at mysite.com/issues/post-title

It looks insanely simple, yet it isn't working for me. I went into Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and entered "world" where it says Category base. I don't know how to add "Issues," because you can apparently only add one category here.

Then I went into Posts > Categories and created two categories - World and Issues. I then created a new post and assigned it to the category World. (I also entered a lower case slug version.) But the post displays at mysite.com/post-title, not mysite.com/world/post-title.

In summary, I would like to be able to 1) create a category (e.g. World), 2) create a new post and assign it to that category, and 3) see that category represented in the URL structure (e.g. mysite.com/world/post-title).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this help? http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Actually, it might... I've already read it a few times, but I think I may have just spotted my mistake. I just created a new post titled "World." In the sidebar, under categories, I see listed Uncategorized and World. My post shows up under both. To cut to the chase, I THINK the problem is that it's assigned to two categories, so I need to unassign it from Uncategorized. Let me see if that works...

Comment: It looks like it isn't going to let me modify the URL's. If I click on "Uncategorized," it displays a list of posts in that category. As I'm creating a new post, I can edit the URL, but if I try to make it world/post-title, it defaults to worldpost-title.